# What is the use of batchSize in Input Configuration in spark connector for mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark

I was going through the docs [spark connector for mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/configuration/#input-configuration)

There I found this **"batchSize"** for readconfig.

I was wondering

1. How batchSize will have impact in reading the data?
2. Will there be any usecase which uses batchSize for reading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in the official code, [batchSize](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/fff1f8dd3c4000ecf7f5716139607d0e8db55358/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/config/ReadConfig.scala#L375) is a member of [ReadConfig](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/config/ReadConfig.scala#L375), therefore is involved every time that you use MongoDB driver to load data in Spark, aka via [MongoRDD](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/a13f846badc14ca08666ea402248f13958702caf/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/rdd/MongoRDD.scala#L192).

In the definition of [ReadConfig](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/config/ReadConfig.scala#L375) it is stated that:

> The optional size for the internal batches used within the cursor

That is, how many records (documents) each batch of the MongoDB cursor should contain. That implies that, the value of *batchSize* should always be > 1.

The *batchSize* property is used by the [MongoRDD](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/a13f846badc14ca08666ea402248f13958702caf/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/rdd/MongoRDD.scala#L192) class of the MongoDB driver, and consequently by [AggregateIterable](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/a36c642537721785c17636d625188f546f8dc6bf/driver-sync/src/main/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.java#L62) class of the MongoDB [client](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver). In addition you can check the code of [AggregateIterableImpl](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/a36c642537721785c17636d625188f546f8dc6bf/driver-sync/src/main/com/mongodb/client/internal/AggregateIterableImpl.java#L188).

How does it affect your Spark program?

1. Larger batchSize (i.e 1000), reduces network overhead by fetching multiple records at once hence making less network round trips.
2. Be careful not setting this too high otherwise you might see an OOM exception occurring in your executor. In other words, make sure that *batchSize x rowSize(KB)* is lower than executor's available memory.

Related resources:

- [Mongo with java - find query with batchsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683581/mongo-with-java-find-query-with-batchsize)
- [Bulk Operations in MongoDB](https://www.dbkoda.com/blog/2017/10/01/bulk-operations-in-mongoDB)
- [MongoDB performance tuning tips](https://farenda.com/mongodb/mongodb-performance-tuning/)